# Is python 3.4 backward compatible with python 3.3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3, python-3.4

Assuming that somebody's concerned only about packages and codes that already work under python 3.3, can they migrate safely to 3.4 without worrying about backward incompatibilities?

This is concerning me because I have to setup a development environment compiling all the sources from scratch, but I'm not sure if it's ok to directly jump into having 3.4 as the only option (assuming 3.3 used to be the only option).

Comment: See [Porting to Python 3.4 in What's New in Python 3.4 documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#porting-to-python-3-4)

Comment: You can try using virtualenv and testing it out with different packages in an isolated environment: http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/

Comment: What do you mean by "backward incompatibilities"? There is no change in syntax, so from that point of view there aren't any problems. There is a number of bug-fixes and small changes in some standard library module, but I doubt you'd bee affected.

Comment: Have you considered testing it to find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For almost everything it will be compatible...

http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html

but look at deprecated, removed and specially Porting to Python 3.4 section